# access violation reading location 0x000000004

Tags: c++, visual-c++, access-violation

I am doing a C++ coding practice in Visual Studio and keep having this problem shown as title. I know where the problem happens but I don't why it happens and how to solve it. Please help me with this.

class_templete.h

```
typedef std::string QuestionName;
class ClassTemplete
{
public:
    ClassTemplete(Question iQuestionName);
private
    static std::map<QuestionName,ClassTemplete *> questionName_questionPointer_map_;
}
```

class_templete.cpp

```
map<QuestionName, ClassTemplete *> ClassTemplete::questionName_questionPointer_map_;

ClassTemplete::ClassTemplete(QuestionName iQuestionName)
{
    ClassTemplete::questionName_questionPointer_map_[iQuestionName] = this;
}
```

chapter1_question1.h

```
class C1Q1 : public ClassTemplete
{
public:
    C1Q1(QuestionName iQuestionName) : ClassTemplete(iQuestionName) {};
private:
    static QuestionName question_name_;
    static C1Q1 question_instance_;
}
```

chapter1_question1.cpp

```
QuestionName C1Q1::question_name_ = "C1Q1";
C1Q1 C1Q1::question_instance_(C1Q1::question_name_);
```

I found out that problem happens at this place when I run the program:

```
ClassTemplete::questionName_questionPointer_map_[iQuestionName] = this;
```

However, I cannot explain why it happens.

Please feel free to contact me if more information is required.

Kind regards,

Yi Ji

Comment: Sounds like `ClassTemplete::questionName_questionPointer_map_` is uninitialized, or initialized to NULL and array subscripting on this invalid map is causing you to try to store something at **0x000...4**

Comment: You tried to dereference a null pointer.

Comment: In fact, the more I think about this, this sounds like an initialization issue on a singleton defined in a different translation unit (class_templete.cpp). This is not the proper way to use a singleton, accessor methods that wrap them are the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where is `QuestionName C1Q1:::question_name_` located relative to `ClassTemplate::questionName_questionPointer_map_`? They seem to be both variables with static storage duration, i.e., they are constructed before `main()` is run. However, the C++ compiler/linker orders the construction of such global objects only with one translation unit (in which case the objects are constructed top to bottom), not between translation units (in which case the objects are constructed in a random order).

You problem looks as if `ClassTemplate::questionName_questionPointer_map` would be constructed after `C1Q1::question_name_`. That is, when `C1Q1::question_name_` is constructed, an object which is not, yet, constructed is being accessed.

The conventional fix is to make the `static` object other objects depend on *not* an object but rather a function with a local `static` variable to which a reference is returned:

```
std::map<QuestionName,ClassTemplete *>&
ClassTemplete::questionName_questionPointer_map_() {
    static std::map<QuestionName,ClassTemplete *> rc;
    return rc;
}
```

(note that this construction is *not* thread-safe when you don't use C++11; it *is* thread-safe when using C++11).

Comment: +1 and I wish I could add in another one for the time it took to dissect this. As always, an excellent job, sir.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks. I think, I have seen this exact problem just often enough, i.e., I just needed to confirm the relevant signs (global objects depending on each other).

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thank you so much as your solution works when I return the reference of a local static variable. However, I do wander if there is a solution to use static variable questionName_questionPointer_map_ of ClassTemplate in this case. If I use local static variable, the one I defined before is less than useless. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `std::map::insert`, you can't do `ClassTemplete::questionName_questionPointer_map_[iQuestionName] = this;` when you insert a new key in the map.

This code should work:

```
ClassTemplete::questionName_questionPointer_map_.insert(std::make_pair(iQuestionName, this));
```